# Calling the classes in java and accessing the variables

Tags: java, class

I'm having an issue calling a class in the correct way. I have created a second class called "Questions" and I have created an instance of it under my main class like below:

```
Questions QuestionBank = new Questions ();
```

I expected to access all my variables from `Questions` as `QuestionBank.Score`, however when I do this `QuestionBank` is highlighted in red. `Questions.Score` works fine but doesn't match the instructions I have used.

Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide your source code?

Comment: Hi, depends on the visibility of the fields- [public, private or protected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-package-private-public-protected-and-private) if fields are public, then you should be able to access like you expecting- `instanceName.variableName`, but its not so safe. If you want to have "shared" class variable, then you can mark it as `public static` and you will be able to access by `ClassName.variableName`, btw `due the convention instances should start lowercase`

Answer (score 2):

Since your question is pretty vague and difficult to understand, I feel  [this](https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/accessing_class_variables.html) can be a very good understanding guide for you to understand.

Let me know of you have any problems. :)

Answer (score 2):

> Questions.Score works fine

That is likely because you have declared your score ***static***

```
public static int Score;
```

This means the `Score` variable belongs to the Questions class itself and there is only one of it. No matter how many times you do `new Questions()` to create a new instance, there will only be one `Score` variable which belongs to the `Questions` class and not instances of the `Questions` class. This explains why you can only access `Score` by `Questions.Score` and not `QuestionBank.Score`.

To solve this simply remove the static modifier.

```
public int Score;
```

Read up on [What does the 'static' keyword do in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class).

Answer (score 0):

start with the look of [java visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-package-private-public-protected-and-private)

Let me say you will class like this

```
public class VariableAccessibility {
    public static int STATICVARIABLE = 1;
    public static final int STATICVARIABLECONSTANT = 1;


    int protectedVariable = 1; //protected is default
    public int publicVariable = 1;
    private int privateVariable = 1;

    public int getPrivateVariable() {
        return privateVariable;
    }
    public void setPrivateVariable(int privateVariable) {
        this.privateVariable = privateVariable;
    }
}
```

Then you can / cannot to do following

```
VariableAccessibility varAccess = new VariableAccessibility();
int value = varAccess.publicVariable;   //works because its public variable
int staticVariable = varAccess.STATICVARIABLE; //works
int consVar = varAccess.STATICVARIABLECONSTANT; //works, because its static

//int privateVar = varAccess.privateVariable; //not visible
int privateVar = varAccess.getPrivateVariable(); //works, call "getter" will be operating with private class variable
```

//static variables values modification
    VariableAccessibility.STATICVARIABLE = 5; //you can do, because static but not final
    //VariableAccessibility.STATICVARIABLECONSTANT = 5; //cannot to do, because its final

Basically, its a good point to have all what is possible marked as `private` (with private modifier) and if needed, then create/generate getters and setters (methods with get / set in the name).

- **public** variables are visible everywhere and you can modify them straightly.
- **private** are not visible without getters/setters, protected should be visible in the same package scope.

static and final are having special purpose:

- **static** variables are "shared" cross all instances
- **final** are not modifiable, in general.